# Client(cocos2d-x) <-> Server(php) How to send Server Data back to Cleint?

Tags: php, c++, post, backend

i am developing some stuff with cocos2d-x and my webserver.
My target is to send Data from mobile Device(Iphone, cocos2d-x) to my server (php) and back to mobile Device.
My Idea is to do this with CCHttpClient, but how can i get an aswere from my server?

Device -> HttpClient -> Data methode "POST" -> Server, deal with data and send variabel "x" back

So how can i send anything back?

best regards
TO

PS: I am German, so sorry for some English-mistakes XD

Comment: `echo` is the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

i think u are just should do echo json_encode( $data ); exit;  Try that.